# Android app with 2 launcher icons with separate taskAffinity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-launcher, launchmode, taskaffinity

I have app with 2 launcher icons and 2 different Activities. Manifest file is as like below:

```
....
    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:taskAffinity="my.package.com.MyActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MySettings"
        android:label="@string/settings"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:taskAffinity="my.package.com.MySettings">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
....
```

I want `MyActivity` to be default screen to be opened after installing, so i used `.category.DEFAULT`.

`action.MAIN` and `category.LAUNCHER` are to show two separate launcher icons (1 for `MyActivity`, 1 for `MySettings`).

**Problem:** When i open `MyActivity`, `MySettings` screen is also gets opened. I want each launcher icon to open its corresponding Activity only. I have used `taskAffinity` for each Activity to solve problem but it did not work. I think to make `taskAffinity` work, Activity must be started with flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` which i can not in my case (both are launch Activities).

I have also tried to use `android:launchMode="singleTask"` but it did not work either.

How to make each launcher icon to open only its Activity ?

**UPDATE:** Sorry, i realized `MyActivity` does not open `MySettings`, it seemed  so though. `MyActivity` did not have UI, so it showed blank screen which is similar to `MySettings`. `taskAffinity` works correct. I have added `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"` to `MyActivity` to hide UI.

Answer (score 1):

Just use two different images for your apps to launch.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MySettings"
        android:label="settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher2"
        android:taskAffinity="my.package.com.MySettings">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: @Jemshit I have edited my answer. Its working as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I solved that way:

```
<activity
   android:name="andynaz.android.hyperfcalc.MainActivity"
   android:label="@string/app_name" >
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
   android:name="andynaz.android.hyperfcalc.MainActivity2"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher2">
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I did not use the taskAffinity, but I indicated the fully specified name of Activity classes (other than using 2 different images).